# Custom Metadata Loader tool for Production

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, custom, loader

Looking for input from others that have used the Metadata Loader tool for their Production Org. This is what I've been trying to do:

Try the "Deploy to Salesforce" Button directly from this website to one of our Production Org.
[image]
I received an error message similar to the one in my email below
[image]
Probably because, according to this website this button doesn't work with Production Orgs 
[image]
So then, I tried to deploy it via the workbench method (making sure to follow the Github instructions).
It's unclear however what boxes should be checked and here's what I tried:
[image]

But it didn't work and I got the following error message:

[image]

Let me know if you think that there is an easy fix or if you think something completely different should be done. 
Thanks!

---

@daniel Ballinger: I'm adding my previous comment as an answer so that I can include the screenshots that wouldn't come through in comments.

I tried what you wrote above but if failed (I also checked the "Ignore Warnings" box but that didn't change anything):

[image]

And that's what the error message looks like when I click on the "codeCoverageWarnings (15)":

[image]

I have to admit that I don't understand what your first option means ... What should I do concretely to achieve that?

I did try your second option at the very beginning but that was the error message that I got:
[image]
New error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried it in a Sandbox and it worked like a charm! I was hoping to be able to use it directly in the Production Org, but oh well. I'll just do it in Sandbox and then deploy the new metadata to Production from there. Not ideal but that works! Thanks for everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when using the Metadata API deploy via Workbench the issue is the **Test Level:  "RunLocalTests"** setting.

[image]

During the deployment the Metadata is performing the [following](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm):

> **RunLocalTests**—All tests in your org are run, except the ones that originate from installed managed packages. This test level is the default for production deployments that include Apex classes or triggers.

In your case there is a local test class `LightningSelfRegisterControllerTest` that currently has a test failure. Likely this would have been true even before attempting to install the package. But it may also have been an interaction with something in the new metadata that is causing the failure.

Some options:

1. Get all the local test classes passing before trying the installation again. (Preferred option in case there is something in the package affecting your org).  To achieve this you can completely ignore the package you are trying to deploy. Instead, run all the tests that are already present in the org. If any fail these will need to be addressed. How you do that will depend on the tests in question.
2. Try the deploy again using the "NoTestRun" testLevel. **NOTE: This will not work on a production org deployment that will enforce coverage requirements.**
3. Run just the tests specific to the package being deployed. Use the "RunSpecifiedTests". Here you will need to identify the names of **all** the test classes being deployed and provide them as a comma separated list in the "Run Tests" section.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.                                                                                                      I tried what you wrote but it failed (I also checked the "Ignore Warnings" box but that didn't change anything):



And that's what the error message looks like when I click on the "codeCoverageWarnings (15)":



I have to admit that I don't understand what your first option means ... What should I do concretely to achieve that?

I did try your second option at the very beginning but that was the error message that I got:

Comment: @user7417 Apologies, I forgot you were deploying to a production org. I'll modify the answer to address this and clarify the first option as well.

Comment: Hello Again Daniel. #1:I tried that, and that resulted in the first error message that I sent you. I tried to google that error message but couldn't figure out what to do exactly. #2:Yes, the error message told me that when I tried the "NoTestRun" #3: I did try that too but maybe didn't find all of them. I got another error.  I'll attach a screenshot of this error and the zip file I'm using as well to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

At this link you can find a Cloud version to upload massive custom metadata type.

https://whispering-escarpment-39582.herokuapp.com/